# Multiply Google Query Results Using Different Factors Per Row

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, google-query-language

I have a query that returns multiple rows per each key used. Each key has a different quantity that I would like to use as a factor to multiply each row by. I would like every result to be multiplied by the same factor set to KEY 1.

For example, all 3 cells in the multiply column for Key "45492" I would like multiplied by 1,600. I have the query used posted here, and the complete sheet too. I created a "TEST PAGE" that has all the necessary information to recreate a complete, usable function.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nKWxcGnwm7FCnqbSZRWKODv51lInNDm3Fo_toAJ5qxY/edit?usp=sharing

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(
QUERY({material_items}, 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B3:B)&"'", 0),
""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(E3:E="",,G3:G*IFNA(VLOOKUP(E3:E, B3:C, 2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Would there be a way to concatenate that solution inside of the query itself? That way, the entire process can be done with one function rather than two. The reason behind that is I plan to nest the query shown on the test page inside of another query. So the end function will sum the "multiply column" for each of the matching numbers in the "don't worry about" column. Here is the nested query as is, which doesn't include your solution, it only returns the non multiplied value:

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(
VLOOKUP(B4:B,
QUERY({QUERY({material_items},
"where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, item_list_typeids)&"'", 0)},
"select Col2, sum(Col3) where Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B4:B)&"' group by Col2 label sum(Col3) ''", 0),
2,0)
,""))

Comment: @MichaelJetzer try: `=ARRAYFORMULA({IFNA(
QUERY({material_items}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B3:B)&"'", 0)), IF(IFNA(
QUERY({material_items}, 
 "select Col1 where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B3:B)&"'", 0))="",,IFNA(
QUERY({material_items}, 
 "select Col3 where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B3:B)&"'", 0))*IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(
QUERY({material_items}, 
 "select Col1 where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B3:B)&"'", 0)), B3:C, 2, 0)))})` see your sheet